# changing the step size/learning rate in artificial intelligence problems

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, reinforcement-learning

The vast majority of update equations usually come in the form of:

$\text{new estimate} \longleftarrow \text{old estimate} + \text{step size}[\text{current reward} - \text{old estimate}]$

The step size in the simples of problems is commonly written as $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{n}$. But in more nonstationary problems (where the interaction between the agent and the environment changes from time to time), it is wise to change this step size (also known as learning rate).

Two conditions have been placed as to what would qualify as an acceptable $\alpha$. They must satisfy the following conditions: $\displaystyle\sum \alpha = \infty$ and $\displaystyle\sum \alpha^2 < \infty$. It is easy to see that $\alpha = \dfrac{1}{n}$ satisfies both conditions.

My question is: Why are these conditions in place? Can you kindly explain the intuition why these conditions are used. Also, is there another $\alpha$, aside from $\dfrac{1}{n}$ that is commonly used in practise?

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify your notation a bit? What is $n$? What are you summing over?

Comment: @cgo Have you read any material on Stochastic approximation and Robbins-Munro procedure?

Comment: @Sycorax $n$, i believe, is the number of turns. In the simple case, it makes sense to be the number of turns. But the definition of a step size can change in more complex problems.

Comment: @LucasRoberts I haven't. Thank you for pointing me to these materials.

Comment: What @LucasRoberts has quoted is exactly where you need to be looking reference-wise. Here is the wiki on [stochastic approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_approximation). As it would seem that your context is one of reinforcement learning, there is a small section that also addresses your question directly on p33 of *Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction (second ed.)* by Sutton and Barto.

Comment: I saw it now. But then it also tells you "Although sequences of step-size parameters that meet these convergence conditions are often used in theoretical work, they are seldom used in applications and empirical research." --- so what are being used in applications and empirical research?